# Can google test handle multithreaded test output on windows

Tags: unit-testing, googletest, boost-unit-test-framework

I just hit a problem with [boost unit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/test/doc/html/utf.html) running on windows where the output from multiple threads is not atomic, so it corrupts the output XML which confuses the CI system if I put any tests or messages in any threads other than the main thread.

I can't see any [boost unit option](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/runtime-config/reference.html) to control this, so am wondering if this is something that [google test](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/) can do which would make it worth switching to google test instead (searching the wiki didn't find me anything).

Or is there some other approach I should use (it's useful when running a test from the command line on linux to see this output. but I don't want it to break my windows CI)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GTest's output is mutex-protected, so multi-threading doesn't produce garbled output.

The function which generally does this work is [`AddTestPartResult`](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/source/browse/trunk/src/gtest.cc?r=649#3699).  At line 3713, you can see the lock being applied:

```
internal::MutexLock lock(&mutex_);
```

and then at 3732 the result is printed in this call:

```
impl_->GetTestPartResultReporterForCurrentThread()->ReportTestPartResult(result);
```